# Extension method restricted to objects containing specific properties

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there any way to create an extension method whose parameter's only constraint is having specifically-named properties.
e.g.:

```
public static bool IsMixed<T>(this T obj) where T:?
{
    return obj.IsThis && obj.IsThat;
}
```

I tried to declare the `obj` as dynamic but it's not allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is often called "duck typing". (Because when you call foo.Quack() all you care about is that it quacks like a duck.) Non-dynamic duck typing is not a feature of C#, sorry!

If you *really* have no type information about the argument, you can use dynamic in C# 4:

```
public static bool IsAllThat(this object x)
{
    dynamic d = x;
    return d.IsThis || d.IsThat;
}
```

But it would be better to come up with some interface or some such thing that describes the types at compile time.

Comment: So just to confirm, you would get a runtime error if properties are not there so you would have to wrap with a try/catch.

Comment: @Sasquiha: Correct; the dynamic code assumes that the code you are executing dynamically is *correct*. If that assumption is violated then an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

you would have to get T to implement an interface, then use that in the constraint.

Comment: the T is unknown, other than it's a class. It could be even an anonymous type. I don't need it to implement a specific interface, I need it to contain two boolean specifically-named properties.
Is defining an interface/base class and having each object implementing it the only way to achieve my goal, you're familiar with?

Comment: @user: If you *need* `T` to contain two specifically named properties then you are requiring to `T` to implement an interface. Conceptually, even if you don't want to do it in code, this is what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot do what you're looking to with generic constraints, you could use reflection to check the type at runtime to determine whether it has those properties and dynamically get their values.

Disclaimer: I'm doing this off the top of my head, I may be slightly off in the implementation.

```
public static bool IsMixed(this object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();

    PropertyInfo isThisProperty = type.GetProperty("IsThis", typeof(bool));
    PropertyInfo isThatProperty = type.GetProperty("IsThat", typeof(bool));

    if (isThisProperty != null && isThatProperty != null)
    {
        bool isThis = isThisProperty.GetValue(this, null);
        bool isThat = isThatProperty.GetValue(this, null);

        return isThis && isThat;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Object must have properties IsThis and IsThat.",
            "obj"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `public static bool IsMixed(this object obj) { var d = (dynamic)obj; return d.IsThis && d.IsThat; }` instead, and let the runtime worry about reflection, performance etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. In absence of appropriate generic type constraints this is the best possible solution

Comment: @Akash: I'd suggest you try some comparative benchmarking rather than basing your performance judgements on just reading the code. It might be true that a single call will be faster using plain reflection than using `dynamic`, but if this code is called often -- a reasonable assumption for utility/extension methods -- then `dynamic` will be much faster overall than plain reflection.

Comment: @LukeH, yes you are right, dynamic does look faster then reflection but the performance is only due to caching, as internally it does use reflection. But this is only true if scope of dynamic object is wider, in this case I dont know what will be performance.

Comment: @Akash, @LukeH: The real benefit of dynamic here is not the performance (though the caching layer should speed up performance if the code is called frequently.) The real benefit is that **"dynamic" makes the code look like what it means**, rather than overwhelming the reader with the mechanisms of reflection. If you're the kind of person who cares deeply about performance then you shouldn't be using either technique, so you might as well use the one that looks nice.

Comment: Now, that said, dynamic does have the possible disadvantage that the code has to be *correct*. With reflection you can say "oh, there is no such property" and do whatever you want to handle the error condition -- ignore it, throw an exception of your choice, whatever. With "dynamic" if that happens then you get an exception of the runtime's choice, end of story.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much the only way to do this is to have an interface as the base of the class you are tring to operate on:

```
interface iMyInterface
{

}

public static bool IsMixed<T>(this T obj) where T: iMyInterface
{
   return obj.IsThis && obj.IsThat;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is the benefit of the generic approach here? Why not simply extend IMyInterface, instead of extending all types? Did you intend IMyInterface to have properties IsThis and IsThat? Why are they not in the interface declaration?

Comment: @Eric Lippert, yes, I was in a bit of a hurry and since I figured that was trivial, I left did not add the properties to the interface.